# While editing a post, is it possible to see difference between original and my edit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editor

I edited a post, but until I saw someone else had edited same post after me and I clicked to see the difference, I wasn't aware that I accidentally had removed a number of lines from the original post.

Is there a way to see the difference between original post and my edit while editing?

Would have been great to have a difference view while editing, so the edit mode would have the following panes:

- the original post
- the one I edit
- the result, showing either result of edit, or if I set focus on the original, show the result of origin. (Instead of having a result pane for each origin and edit.)

Comment: Be more careful. Review your edit after it is applied, especially if you have a habit of "just removing a number of lines by mistake". The focus shouldn't be on what you have changed while editing. It should be on making the post as good as it can  be.

Comment: Of course, that is the way I intended. But even so, it would be helpful to have the kind of view I described to mitigate that risk. I guess I am not the first one.

Comment: I would find this useful, and I am probably one of the more careful people around. It would often be helpful to see the original while editing, if not some "difference" view. The way I'd do it is just use the side-by-side rendered view that's displayed when reviewing edits, below the regular edit box. Maybe have a checkbox that controls whether you see just the full rendered, edited post or the side-by-side.

Comment: @roombatron That's a false premise. You can't judge if a post is "the best it can be" solely by the post-edit state. Seeing the diff would help editors ensure they haven't screwed anything up (removed a detail or changed a fact) before saving the revision.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78652/add-an-option-for-side-by-side-diff-before-posting-an-edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly, but there's a workaround making use of the grace period. Once you finish a substantial-ish edit, go ahead and look at the revisions and there you'll see the diff; you then have five minutes or a bit less to fix any mistakes without leaving any permanent trace.

Personally, I wouldn't mind the full thing, as I often run through a number of nigh-instinctive fixes (removing thanks, fixing grammar/spelling/minor markdown glitches, and several others) and I don't necessarily remember all the fixes I applied when I write up the summary 90 seconds later, at least without thinking hard about it. (The more unusual stuff like fixing phrasing, re-indenting code, fixing titles or tags, and so forth stick in my head a lot better.)

Comment: Is there a grace period if you're *suggesting* an edit?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: If memory serves (it's been a few weeks), editing again while a suggested edit is pending will change the suggestion without invalidating any of the previous reviews.